I am trying to create UI framework using selenium java but facing issue in initiating webdriver not sure whether this is advisable to do
I'm creating a Selenium automation framework using java. When passing WebDriver from LoginPage back to BasePage, I got an error so I'm using driver1 in BasePage. Not sure of the correct way to do this.
public class Basepage {
    public WebDriver driver;
    public Login lp;

    public void reportStep(String stepinfo, String status, WebDriver driver1) {
        int snapnumber = takeSnap(driver1);
        if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("pass")) {
            test.pass(stepinfo, MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromPath(".././snaps/img" + snapnumber + ".png").build());
        } else if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("fail")) {
            test.fail(stepinfo, MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromPath(".././snaps/img" + snapnumber + ".png").build());
            throw new RuntimeException("See extend report for more details");
        }
    }

    public int takeSnap(WebDriver driver1) throws IOException {
        int rannumber = (int) (Math.random() * 999999 + 1000000);
        File source = ((TakesScreenshot) driver1).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        File target = new File("./snaps/img" + rannumber + ".png");
        FileUtils.copyFile(source, target);

        return rannumber;
    }

    public class Login extends Basepage {
        private WebDriver driver;
        public static Logger logfile = LogManager.getLogger(Login.class.getName());

        @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@name='username']")
        private WebElement username;

        public Login(WebDriver driver) {
            this.driver = driver;
            PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        }

        public Login enterUserName(String uName) throws IOException {
            try {
                username.sendKeys(uName);
                reportStep("Username entered successfully ", "pass", driver);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                reportStep("Username not entered successfully " + e, "fail", driver);
            }

            return this;
        }

        @Test()
        public void LoginOrangeHrm(String uName, String pWord, String title ){           
            Login lp = new Login(driver);         
            lp.enterUserName(uName)
    }
}


Here's a simple example of a BasePage that is inherited by a LoginPage page object and then used by LoginTest.
BasePage.java
package selenium;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class BasePage {
    protected WebDriver driver;

    public BasePage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public void click(By locator) {
        driver.findElement(locator).click();
    }

    public void type(By locator, String text) {
        driver.findElement(locator).sendKeys(text);
    }
}

LoginPage.java
package selenium;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class LoginPage extends BasePage {
    private final By usernameLocator = By.id("username");
    private final By passwordLocator = By.id("password");
    private final By submitButtonLocator = By.cssSelector("button[type='submit']");

    public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
    }

    public void login(String username, String password) {
        type(usernameLocator, username);
        type(passwordLocator, password);
        click(submitButtonLocator);
    }
}

LoginTest.java
package selenium;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class LoginTest {
    public void SimpleLoginTest() {
        String username = "username";
        String password = "password";
    
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        new LoginPage(driver).login(username, password);
        ...
    }
}

BasePage handles the driver instance and provides standard Selenium functionality like .click() and .type() (aka .sendKeys()) and more can be added.
LoginPage represents a typical login page. It contains locators for the username, password, and submit button. It also provides the login() method to log in a user.
LoginTest is a simple login test that just logs in. For a real test, you'd want to have asserts to validate various items on the page, etc.
This is just a simple example but provides the framework that can be expanded into many page objects and tests.

Thanks Jeff, i am trying to use page factory in all pages , using page factory can we achieve this webdriver initiation.

The Selenium lead and devs recommend that you NOT use PageFactory, see this video. If you need PageFactory, you should be able to convert what I have pretty simply.

If this or any other answer was useful please upvote it. Once you find the answer to your question, please mark it as accepted so the question isn't left unanswered.

create a Base class with driver initialization in static method and class variable like public static WebDriver driver = null;. then everywhere call this BaseClass.initialization() to get the driver and set the properties as per need

I have already created basemethod  @BeforeMethod
public void webdriverCreation() {
System.out.println("before method");
driver = WebDriverManager.chromedriver().create();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/auth/login");
implicitwait(20);
logfile.info("url entered successfully");
}
